# using notepad++ to search for Dxxxx and replace all string before and after

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking to use notepad++ to search for `Dxxxx` (x is a 4 digit number) and remove everything before and after this.

For example:

```
this string is an example of D1234 the find and replace I want to do
```

Would become

```
D1234
```

Comment: Must `D1234` be isolated (with spaces for example) or could it be inside a long string? What should be the result for `ABCD123456789` or if there are multiple `D1234` like `...D1234XYZD1234...`?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect? Could you gives some examples and expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Tick on regular expressions. 
Search for

```
(.*)(D[0-9]{4,4})(.*)
```

and replace with

```
\2
```

Comment: You might also shorten it to a single capturing group and a single 4 `.*(D[0-9]{4}).*` and replace with `\1`